# How to make exam instructions attached to the end of only the first page header?

Tags: header-footer, tcolorbox, geometry, exam

I need to fix following code to make the instructions attached to the end of the first page header so that the exam body on the first page is pushed down instead of pushing the header up.

### First page header

[image]

---

---

### Second page header

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,enumitem}
\usepackage[raster,skins,fitting]{tcolorbox}


\newcommand\headerBody{%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[
        raster valign = bottom,
        valign = bottom,
        raster columns = 2,
        blankest,
        raster before skip = 0ex, raster after skip = 1ex,
        ]
        \tcboxfit[add to width = 2cm, halign = flush left,height=3em, valign=bottom]{%
            First\\
            Second\\
        }
        \tcbitem[add to width = -2cm, halign = flush right,] \includegraphics[height = 3em]{example-image}
    \end{tcbitemize}}

\newcommand{\Instructions}{%
    \begin{tcbraster}[
        raster columns = 1,
        valign = center,
        raster before skip = 1ex, raster after skip = 1ex,
        blankest,
        height = 14em, 
        ]
        \tcboxfit[ halign = flush left , right = 1ex]{%
            \textbf{Important Rules:}
            \begin{itemize}[
                label = \textbullet, leftmargin=*, labelsep = \fontdimen2\font, itemsep = 0.5\baselineskip, %nosep
                topsep = 0.5\baselineskip
                ]
                \item One.
                
                \item Two.
            \end{itemize}%
        }       
    \end{tcbraster}
}

\newcommand\FirstHeader{%
    \begin{minipage}[b][][t]{\textwidth}%
        \begin{tcbraster}[
            fit algorithm = hybrid,
            raster equal height = rows,
            raster halign = center, raster valign = center,
            raster equal skip = 0mm, raster force size = false,
            boxsep = 0pt, beforeafter skip = 0pt, leftright skip = 0pt,
            nobeforeafter,
            height = 2em,
            ]
            \headerBody%
            \vspace*{1ex}%
            \hrule%
            \Instructions
        \end{tcbraster}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand\RunningHeader{%
    \begin{minipage}[b][][t]{\textwidth}%
        \begin{tcbraster}[
            fit algorithm = hybrid,
            raster equal height = rows,
            raster halign = center, raster valign = center,
            raster equal skip = 0mm, raster force size = false,
            boxsep = 0pt, beforeafter skip = 0pt, leftright skip = 0pt,
            nobeforeafter,
            height = 2em,
            ]
            \headerBody%
            \vspace*{1ex}%
            \hrule%
        \end{tcbraster}%
    \end{minipage}%
}



\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{}{\FirstHeader}{}
\runningheader{}{\RunningHeader}{}
\firstpagefooter{}{first footer}{}
\runningfooter{}{running footer}{}


\usepackage[
a4paper,
includehead, 
top = 0 mm,
headheight = 5em,
headsep = 0\baselineskip,
includefoot,
foot = 0 em,
bottom = 5.5 em,
showframe
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    text
    \newpage
    another text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choice: use `\firstpageheader{}{\RunningHeader}{}`  and

```
\begin{document}
\Instructions

text        

\newpage
another text
\end{document}
```

Second choice, (if for some reason you need/want to include the Instructions in your header): with your same preamble

```
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{includehead, 
           textheight=22.7 cm, % to be adjusted according the height of Instructions <<<
            headheight = 50em,
            headsep = 0\baselineskip,
            includefoot,
            foot = 0 em,
            bottom = 5.5 em,
            showframe}
    
        text    
\restoregeometry    

    \newpage
    another text
\end{document}
```

The results are similar, with the first option being the simplest answer. (I added more items to test the second option)

[image: b]